# DataGridView for evry id show other datagrid view

Tags: c#

I am making little program and now made a data grid view which is showing from my database all `Project`. In database i have following tables `Project`, `Category`, `Job`. Now i want thath when user click in one line it will show new form with data grid view which will show Categoryes which are connected to Project. I know thath i should just drop from Data Sources but i cant because i have intermediate table. I already have SQL Query how i get the info from the target (Category).

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Kategorija c
INNER JOIN Project_Category pc on pc.cId = c.cId
INNER JOIN Project p on pc.pId = p.pId
```

So pId should be input parameter.

Thanks for any suggestion and help!

Answer (score 0):

I am confused what is your exact requirement, but I think you are looking some think like this

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Kategorija c, Project_Category pc, Project p
WHERE pc.cId = c.cId and pc.pId = p.pId and p.pId=@selectedProjectID
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hey yes i know its hard to understand. I wil try to explain more. So i am doing a Query in C# (DataSet designer) which will fill Datagrid view with sql query which i posted in my main post. But with such query i posted ts not working. What should i change because Kategorija(Category) its not directly connected to Project.

Comment: In my answer `@selectedProjectID` is a parameter. Change it with `pid` or project id and run it, then check result.